# How can I make this function into a loop? Python

Tags: python, function, loops, emoji

I would like to call again the function to return a new list with 5 results of sampled_list. Thank you guys

```
import random
emoji_list  = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

sampled_list=random.sample(emoji_list, k=5)

def listToString(sampled_list):
    # initialize an empty string
    str1 = ""
    # traverse in the string
    for i in sampled_list:
        str1 += i
        # return string
    return str1
```

Comment: If you want the function to return different things each time you call it, then put the bit where you call `random.sample` inside your function.

Comment: You want to call a function multiple times? Sorry it's hard to understand.

Comment: Also in your function use `''.join(sampled_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you wanted something like this:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5eLKyU1TSE1Nz8rM7ikKDMvXUPTiksBCMBC8TmZxSUKCrYK0eof5s9oUNdRANHNULoFSjdC6TYo3QqlmyD0ksXqOiBuF1S4HULPhErPhBnXCaV7oHQvhF66AcqfAaWnQ4ybCeXOgtLdUHo2lJ4LpedAXbEKSq@A0MsnQPmToer6oPyVUGs3Q8X7ofxdUD5UfOk2KH@jeiw4wIpSS0qL8hTU1fWy8jPzNCDBq1ecmFuQk6qBCE0dhWxgeJpqanJxFQDDu0QDJew1sQr@/w8A)

```
import random

def emojiString():
    emoji_list  = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    return ''.join(random.sample(emoji_list, k = 5))

print(emojiString())
print(emojiString())
```

Output:

---

If you want to accumulate several results into list do following:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZE7SwQxFIX7@RXpkoFhmsVGsNjeTjtZZCBRs2aSkM0Wdr7F1@6ChTs@sNDFR6UIFv4q/8GY2RxRsTHNl3Nu7k04sRt@zehWXcvSGueJKzQ3ZZJwsUJEabpywTupV1k6m5Cwptaykj1PyBxZoh83402akYY74C64Be6De@B25N0tzRp5BPsgskK5@hp3CJ6Ap5GTZ@gxeB7HVZAX4DF4CV6DV3jFE/gQeT@CPsO5AfQjrn2FP4R@h4Y/eYN@oZ1pYE74vtOE0rxrpGYx3rxXlFYJ9p1mRtZDnjNp@iP5NueLZj4UmUL6Ki@sFZqzXz8TelTzGZ3kT9u/HBvGNJu6/gQ)

```
import random

def emojiString():
    emoji_list  = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    return ''.join(random.sample(emoji_list, k = 5))

def emojiAddToList(l):
    l.append(emojiString())

l = []
emojiAddToList(l)
emojiAddToList(l)
emojiAddToList(l)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['', '', '']
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: is it posible to put the outputs into a new list?

Comment: @MateusNogueira Of cause you can do this. Something [like this](https://tio.run/##jZE7SwQxFIX7@RXpkoFhmsVGsNjeTjtZZCBRs2aSkM0Wdr7F1@6ChTs@sNDFR6UIFv4q/8GY2RxRsTHNl3Nu7k04sRt@zehWXcvSGueJKzQ3ZZJwsUJEabpywTupV1k6m5Cwptaykj1PyBxZoh83402akYY74C64Be6De@B25N0tzRp5BPsgskK5@hp3CJ6Ap5GTZ@gxeB7HVZAX4DF4CV6DV3jFE/gQeT@CPsO5AfQjrn2FP4R@h4Y/eYN@oZ1pYE74vtOE0rxrpGYx3rxXlFYJ9p1mRtZDnjNp@iP5NueLZj4UmUL6Ki@sFZqzXz8TelTzGZ3kT9u/HBvGNJu6/gQ).

Comment: you are very fast, thank you again!

Comment: @MateusNogueira If my answer was helpful to you, please don't forget to Up-Vote it. I see you have enough (more than 15) reputation to do this. UpVoting can be done same place where accepting, there is upper arrow for adding +1 vote to me.

Comment: Yeah, of course. I think its done, can you check?

Comment: @MateusNogueira Yes, I got +1 from you, thanks a lot! :)